# How do you progress through the reportlab canvas?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

Just starting to use the reportlab library. I figured out that 0,0 is the position in the bottom-left corner and I am  using beginText and textlines to write some text. After the text I want to draw an image. But how do I know what position I left at when writing the text?

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import LETTER
canvas = Canvas("report.pdf", pagesize=LETTER)
t= canvas.beginText(30, LETTER[1]-30)
t.textLines(wraped_text)
canvas.drawText(t)
canvas.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use flowables. In the below code example I made a sentence which contains an inline image.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("page.pdf", pagesize=letter)

flowables = []

ptext = '''This sentence is followed by a picture:
<img src="https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-powered-w-70x28.png" width="70" height="28"/>
... some more text'''
flowables.append(Paragraph(ptext))

ptext = 'Next sentence.'
flowables.append(Paragraph(ptext))

doc.build(flowables)
```

Comment: Did the above feedback help you forward?